# Xcode 5 Plugins

Tags: xcode, plugins, xcode5

Coming from Visual Studio & ReSharper world, you could imagine the state of shock when I was first subjected to the 'Xcode' IDE experience... Now I've just gotten used to it *sigh*

I've tried JetBrain's AppCode, it worked well for code editing but not so much for debugging and other stuff, went back to Xcode.

Looking for Xcode 5 Plugin recommendations, anything to enhance the IDE.

Thanks!

Comment: This is rather vague and open ended. Be more specific about what you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are quite a few plugins for Xcode, many of which haven't been updated for Xcode 5 yet. I think the first resource you'd want to look into is Alcatraz, which is a great package manager for Xcode:

http://alcatraz.io

You can install most of the available plugins through Alcatraz.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Answer (score 4):

This depends, hugely, on what type of apps you write and what features you use.

The ones that I'm grateful for every day are Lin+HOStringSense (for inline editing of localized strings and escaped strings, respectively), and ColorSense (for inline display of hardcoded colors, [UIColor someColor] calls, and other good stuff).  It's the simple things that matter the most.

(Edit: how could I forget KSImageNamed?!  A must for a very image-heavy application I maintain.  And VVDocumenter is a nice convenience when you develop libraries for which you intend to autogen Appledoc.)

As I recall, I found all three of these through [this list](http://maniacdev.com/xcode-plugins).  You might look there as well.

Answer (score 2):

I recently compiled a list of what I thought were the most useful Xcode 5 plugins (Most of them available through Alcatraz). [Here's the list](http://iosdevtips.co/post/82232620790/best-xcode-plugins).